# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04?

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have problem with wifi drivers. Connection is very unstable. My laptop is ASUS K550J, with SSD disk and double ram. 
Is it possible that Ub 15.04 comes with more or better wifi drivers?
Should I upgrade to Ub 15.04? And how to?

Comment: Let's try to fix wireless issue in 14.04. There is no difference. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: And you can not directly upgrade 14.04 to 15.04. And it will not solve the driver problem either way.

Answer (score -2):

(tip: change the title in something more directly related to *problems with wifi drivers*. That's what you're actyally trying to solve)

In general, better/different drivers are not necessarily tied to the Ubuntu release you're using. In fact you may be able to install the same driver on different Ubuntu release.

Since you asked it: to upgrade to the latest Ubuntu release, use the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade
```